# UIAlertAction Error

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add some actions to a UIAlertController but I am getting an error when I'm passing it a closure. I want to pass that closure as a handler for an action, but I am getting an error message. [image]

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancel)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)



        let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

          let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "No service", message: "Sorry the phone option is not working right now, try again later", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default , handler: callActionHandler)



        optionMenu.addAction(callAction)


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Only `!` you missed. 
Change the below line

`let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in`

with

`let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in`

That's it !